# Find 1 (or more) strings in a file and insert a line after each match based on the founded string

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following text file:

```
STRONGTUND TR12 REM Mary
STRONGTUND TR12 LAC 78
STRONGTUND TR12 BER -2

STRONGTUND TR13 REM John
STRONGTUND TR13 LAC 100
STRONGTUND TR13 BER -67

STRONGTUND TR14 REM Greg
STRONGTUND TR14 LAC 23
STRONGTUND TR14 BER -6
```

What I want to achieve is the following: Look for a string that matches `STRONGTUND TR\d LAC \d`regex. Once matched, add on a new line another string such as: `STRONGTUND $SAME-TR-NUMBER-AS-MATCHED-STRING LACv8 $INPUT`, where "$INPUT" is variable (could be text or not) and is given to the script to put into each of the lines it creates. Note that $INPUT is different for each line.

In the above text example, the result should be something like:

```
STRONGTUND TR12 REM Mary
STRONGTUND TR12 LAC 78
STRONGTUND TR12 LACv8 212
STRONGTUND TR12 BER -2

STRONGTUND TR13 REM John
STRONGTUND TR13 LAC 100
STRONGTUND TR13 LACv8 234
STRONGTUND TR13 BER -67

STRONGTUND TR14 REM Greg
STRONGTUND TR14 LAC 23
STRONGTUND TR14 LACv8 111
STRONGTUND TR14 BER -6
```

Is this possible without using a programming language (so only with linux tools?)

Comment: Do you mean general purpose programming languages?  `awk` is considered by many as a fine programming language specialized for (formatted) text processing.  Also, you have to show what you tried and what didn't work to get help here!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. For example, like this:

```
awk -v "out=FILE_OUT" '1 { print; print $0 > out }
$0 ~ "STRONGTUND TR[0-9]+ LAC [0-9]+" {
    printf "Enter value: "
    getline val < "-"
    print $1,$2,"LACv8",val > out
}' FILE_IN
```

It will parse file FILE_IN, ask the user for values to put after LACv8 and save the new content to FILE_OUT.